# JavaScript Array attribute change

Tags: javascript

**I have an array like this.**

```
let arr = [
  {
    "ABBRIVATION":"ISB",
    "name":"ISLAMABAD",
  },
  {
    "ABBRIVATION":"RAW",
    "name":"PINDI",
  },
  {
    "ABBRIVATION":"SWB",
    "name":"SWABI",
  },
  {
    "ABBRIVATION":"AQ",
    "name":"AQEEL",
  },
]
```

**I want to change it to like this**
let me explain it a little. I want to assign the abbreviation directly to the name and the iterate through that array

```
let outout = [
  {
    "ISB":"ISLAMABAD"
  },
  {
    "RAW":"ISLAMABAD"
  },
  {
    "SWB":"SWABI"
  },
  {
    "AQ":"AQEEL"
  },
]
```

**that is what I tried**

```
let k = arr.map((item) => {
  return item.ABB = item.name
})
console.log(k)
```

**and here is the output**

```
[ 'ISLAMABAD', 'PINDI', 'SWABI', 'AQEEL' ]
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

this is how you suppose to do it.

```js
arr.reduce((d, c)=>([...d, {[c.ABBRIVATION]: c.name}]),[])
```

```js
let arr = [
  {
    "ABBRIVATION":"ISB",
    "name":"ISLAMABAD",
  },
  {
    "ABBRIVATION":"RAW",
    "name":"PINDI",
  },
  {
    "ABBRIVATION":"SWB",
    "name":"SWABI",
  },
  {
    "ABBRIVATION":"AQ",
    "name":"AQEEL",
  },
]

console.log(arr.reduce((data, current)=>([...data, {[current.ABBRIVATION]: current.name}]),[]))
```

Comment: why are you suppose to do it like this? why must you abuse reduce to work just like map? why? please explain why this is at all better than using map?

Comment: How is `reduce` the better option here? You basically mapped the array without using `map`??

Comment: I agree that this is [useless use of](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat) `reduce`. This code is about 26% slower than the .map solution according to JSBench.

Answer (score 4):

Here you go, use array map, simples

```js
let arr = [
  {
    "ABBRIVATION":"ISB",
    "name":"ISLAMABAD",
  },
  {
    "ABBRIVATION":"RAW",
    "name":"PINDI",
  },
  {
    "ABBRIVATION":"SWB",
    "name":"SWABI",
  },
  {
    "ABBRIVATION":"AQ",
    "name":"AQEEL",
  },
]

let outout = arr.map(({ABBRIVATION, name}) => ({[ABBRIVATION]: name}));
console.log(outout);
```

Answer (score 3):

Nothing more than a simple `Array.prototype.map()` needed.

```js
let arr = [
  {
    ABBRIVATION: "ISB",
    name: "ISLAMABAD",
  },
  {
    ABBRIVATION: "RAW",
    name: "PINDI",
  },
  {
    ABBRIVATION: "SWB",
    name: "SWABI",
  },
  {
    ABBRIVATION: "AQ",
    name: "AQEEL",
  },
];

const result = arr.map(e => ({ [e.ABBRIVATION]: e.name }));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the array of objects (`map` returns a new array) and assign the name to a new key defined by the abbreviation.

You code works the way it does because `item.ABB` is undefined, but you're also assigning `item.name` to it which *does* get returned, so you just get an array of names returned.

```js
const arr=[{ABBRIVATION:"ISB",name:"ISLAMABAD"},{ABBRIVATION:"RAW",name:"PINDI"},{ABBRIVATION:"SWB",name:"SWABI"},{ABBRIVATION:"AQ",name:"AQEEL"}];

const out = arr.map(obj => {
  return { [obj.ABBRIVATION]: obj.name };
});

console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have seen people answer, but most of them use the map function, I provide some other solutions, hoping to expand the thinking

---

**Use [forEach](http://developer.mozilla.org/zh-TW/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function**

```js
const datas = [
  {
    "ABBRIVATION":"ISB",
    "name":"ISLAMABAD",
  },
  {
    "ABBRIVATION":"RAW",
    "name":"PINDI",
  },
  {
    "ABBRIVATION":"SWB",
    "name":"SWABI",
  },
  {
    "ABBRIVATION":"AQ",
    "name":"AQEEL",
  }
];

datas.forEach((obj, i, arr) => {
  const{'ABBRIVATION':k, 'name':v} = obj;
  arr[i] = {[k]:v};
});

console.log(datas);
```

**Use [flatMap](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) function**

```js
const datas = [
  {
    "ABBRIVATION":"ISB",
    "name":"ISLAMABAD",
  },
  {
    "ABBRIVATION":"RAW",
    "name":"PINDI",
  },
  {
    "ABBRIVATION":"SWB",
    "name":"SWABI",
  },
  {
    "ABBRIVATION":"AQ",
    "name":"AQEEL",
  }
];

const result = datas.flatMap(obj => {
  const {'ABBRIVATION':k, 'name':v} = obj;
  return {[k]:v};
});

console.log(result);
```